# Fortinet SSL VPN Client and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vpn

I want to install the Forticlient SSL VPN Client on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've downloaded the latest version from the Fortinent support site but when I try to run the installer (vía command line or GUI) it simply does nothing.

I have tried to install both with and without sudo but nothing happens.

I remember some time ago that I successfully installed the same client in CentOS and the client worked fine.

Can anyone help me to install this?

Comment: Would you please provide the result of that command , e.g any error message ? try launch it in e.g gnome-terminal

Comment: Unfortunately when i run the command in terminal i don't get any error message.

Comment: answer given by cortex for ubuntu 14.04 worked!! Thanks cortex.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04, after install forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.4.2287.tar.gz I had to edit helper/sysconfig.linux.sh.
To compute the ppp0 address, I had to replace the existing line with:
    addr=`ifconfig ppp0 |grep "inet"|awk ' {print $3 }'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have the Ubuntu 64 bit version (at least it was my case). If so, just install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 xterm
```

Comment: This does not work for me: E: Couldn't find package libgtk2.0-0:i386

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using 64bit ubuntu 14.04 (after clean install you have to install these packages)

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 xterm
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had it to work. However it wants you to accept a License Agreement which it will try to open in xterm. So make sure that xterm has been installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Answer (score 0):

install 32-bit libralies.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
```

if you can run tunnel but traffic is not going through the tunnel.

You can try this note on Facebook.

https://www.facebook.com/notes/%E5%B7%9D%E7%AB%AF-%E8%8B%B1%E6%8F%AE/gettin-to-use-forticlient-on-64-bit-linux-system-64-bit-linux-%E3%81%A7%EF%BD%86%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%92%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%89%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%89%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%8E%EF%BD%94%E3%82%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9/410366692372497

i get well on ubuntu 12.10(x64)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386` was still giving me errors when running 12.04.

After executing **`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk`** FortiSSL is now running smoothly without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old question, but I was searching myself for the forti client and now they have a package that do not require the ia-32 libs.
You can download it from [here](https://hadler.me/files/forticlient-sslvpn_4.4.2313-1_amd64.deb).

[More info](https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/)

Comment: I am getting the following error "Dependency is not satisfiable libpango-1.0-0 (>=1.14.0)". I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @JoswinKJ . Please create a question stating your problem, and give me the link here in a comment. Also please state from where you have downloaded the fortinet client.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the package (tar.gz format) from support.fortinet.com. Once you extract the files, open the folders forticlientsslvpn > 32bit or 64bit, run the executable file "forticlientsslvpn" to launch the GUI.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome Juan! Install `openvpn` first and try.To install it,type `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn` in a `terminal` and reboot your system.I think this should solve your issue.

Comment: I've installed it but appears that openvpn client does not be compatible with Fortinet SSL VPN.

Answer (score -2):

only CLI works under Ubuntu 13.10 because packages like `libgtk2` or `ia32-libs` are not available anymore.

Comment: Please see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ia32) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libgtk2.0-0)