# Forticlient SSL VPN binary not running

Tags: vpn, ssl

I've got a Mac running VMWare fusion with Ubuntu 10.10 in that.

I'm currently using the Fortinet client from OSX, but that client is buggy, every time my Mac sleeps I need to reboot to get the SSL/VPN connection working again.

Because I only need the SSL/VPN connection from Ubuntu I tried installing the Fortinet SSL/VPN client in Ubuntu. But I was unsuccesfull.

I took the following steps:

- downloaded the .tar.gz
- `$ tar -xvzf forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2012.tar.gz`
- `$ cd forticlientsslvpn`
- `$ ./forticlientsslvpn`

Then I get the notice:

```
$ bash: ./forticlientsslvpn: No such file or directory
```

(Mind you, the file *is* there)

And now I'm stuck, **what direction can I troubleshoot into**?

---

Notes:
I've tried a couple of different versions:

- [forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2010](http://internal.enterprisecomponent.com/download/FortiClientSSLVPN/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2010.tar.gz)
- [forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2012](http://ftp.cnpq.br/FortiClientSSLVpn/Linux/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2012.tar.gz)
- [forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2147](http://noc.intermax.nl/downloads/fortinet/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2147.tar.gz)

Related question: [Fortinet SSL VPN Client and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134715/fortinet-ssl-vpn-client-and-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the same as in the related question, you are running a 64-bit Ubuntu and the fortinet binary is 32-bit. In 11.10 multiarch was introduced which makes it very easy to install 32-bit and 64-bit libraries at the same time, but Ubuntu 10.10 doesn't have multiarch and that's why installing libgtk2.0-0:i386 doesn't work. With older Ubuntu versions some 32-bit libraries are packaged in the ia32-libs package, doing apt-get install ia32-libs will probably solve your problem.

10.10 doesn't have security support anymore by the way, so it might be a good idea to upgrade to 12.04 LTS anyway.

In short:

```
$ apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: I am indeed running 64-bit Ubuntu (10.10). And your suggestion worked. Thanks!

Comment: Making sure you have libgtk2.0-0:i386 (change the version if necessary) and xterm should suffice, ia32-libs adds many more packages not required for the vpn client.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

this will do :)

Answer (score 0):

./forticlientsslvpn: No such file or directory is missing xterm to display the EULA.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xterm
```