# FortiClient VPN connected but no IP

Tags: networking

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. I managed to install the FortiClient after lots of search and mainly by installing everything suggested on these pages :

- [Fortinet SSL VPN Client and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134715/fortinet-ssl-vpn-client-and-ubuntu-12-04)
- [Forticlient SSL VPN binary not running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142008/forticlient-ssl-vpn-binary-not-running)

Now I have it running and the connection status indicates tunnel running and I see bytes receives and send bytes.

I am trying to connect to remote desktop to a Windows 7 machine but it doesn't work. first thing first I check if I ping the machine and no it doesn't ping.

I looked under Devices - Network Tools, I can see that there was no interface created for the VPN and I don't have an IP for the tunnel. I only have my local network IP.

I tried the 2010 and 21467 versions.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution. The forticlient does not create the routes needed for the tunnel to work as expected. In a terminal type:

```
sudo route add -net [office lan IP] netmask 255.255.254.0 dev ppp0
```

eg:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.38.0 netmask 255.255.254.0 dev ppp0
```

where `192.168.38.0/23` is my office LAN range. My office PC is on `192.168.38.83`. Then when using remmina app I used my office PC IP-Address and got my remote desktop working. My Win7 office PC looks like win XP but at least I can work.

The only problem is that I have to enter this command EACH time I reconnect to the vpn through forticlient.

I added this command in a script in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue (on debian 9) by running:

```
apt-get install ppp
```